# Nextcloud Container and external hdd

Tags: docker, containers, nextcloud

im fairly new to the Docker Container world and im trying to move my Nextcloud server to the container.

i can deploy it successfully on a test environment, but im trying to map an externall HDD that will eventually contain all of the data (profiles/pics/data/etc) as it is on my current server.

my current setup is an ubuntu server 20.04.1 and Nextcloud 18 with an external HDD mounted for storage.

so far i havent been able to map the external drive.

can anyone provide any insights?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you specifically, more information is required, like which docker image are you using and how are you deploying your container. Also, this might be a question for https://serverfault.com/

The general concepts of "mounting" parts of a filesystem into a container are described at [Docker Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and [Bind Mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

Suppose your harddrive is mounted at `/mnt/usb` on the host, you could access it within a docker container at `/opt/usb` when started like this

`docker run -i -t -v /mnt/usb:/opt/usb ubuntu /bin/bash`

Comment: Thank you for the tip.

after reading the links provided related to Volumes and Binds i was able to get the bind on the external HDD.

Thanks!